# Question on a proof of Fraisse's theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory

On page 13 of [this note](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/ag/logik/teaching/2017WS/Model%20theory/Notes.pdf), Fraisse's theorem (theorem 2.2.4) (a countable class of $\mathcal{L}$-structures is an amalgamation class if and only if it is the skeleton of a countable homogeneous $\mathcal{L}$-structure) is proved as follows.

> Assume that $\mathcal{K}$ is an amalgamation class. We will construct a structure as required whose domain is a subset of $\mathcal{N}$. Let $\bar{K} = \langle K_l: l\in \Bbb{N}\rangle$ enumerate $\mathcal{K}$ and let $\langle {a_l}, {b_l},f_l: l\in \Bbb{N}\rangle$ enumerate all triples of the form $(\bar{a_l}, \bar{b_l},{f})$ such that each triple appears infinitely often, where $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ are tuples in $\mathcal{N}$ and $f : \mathcal{N}\to\mathcal{N}$ is a partial function with domain $\bar{a}$ and range $\bar{b}$.
>
> We will construct the required structure as a union of an increasing sequence $\bar{C} = \langle C_n:n\in \Bbb{N}\rangle$ of elements of $\mathcal{K}$, starting with $C_0 = K_0$. We now assume that $C_n$ is already constructed. If $n = 2l$ is even, we apply the joint embedding property to $C_n$ and $K_l$ and obtain an element $C_{n+1}$ of $\mathcal{K}$. We now assume that $n = 2l + 1$ is odd. If at least one of $\bar{a_l}$ or $\bar{b_l}$ is not a subset of $C_n$, let $C_{n+1} = C_n$. If on the other hand both $\bar{a_l}$ and $\bar{b_l}$ are subsets of $C_n$, then we apply the amalgamation property to $id_{A_l} : A_l \to C_n$ and the embedding $f : A_l \to B_l$ that is induced by $f_l$ from the substructure $A_l$ of $C_n$ generated by $\bar{a_l}$ to the stubstructure $B_l$ of $C_n$ generated by $\bar{b_l}$, and obtain an element $C_{n+1}$ of $\mathcal{K}$. Moreover we can choose $C_{n+1}$ such that the embedding from $C_{n}$ to $C_{n+1}$ is equal to $id_{C_{n}}$ and $C_{n}$ is a substructure of $C_{n+1}$.
>   Finally, Let $C =\bigcup \bar{C}$. The even steps of the construction ensure that $\mathcal{K}$ is the skeleton of $C$.

My question is that exactly what is $(\bar{a_l}, \bar{b_l},{f})$? (It does not explain in the proof clearly. ) So I am lost at "If at least one of $\bar{a_l}$ or $\bar{b_l}$ is not a subset of $C_n$".

Comment: It says at the end of the first quoted paragraph: $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ are tuples (could be considered subsets) of $\mathcal{N}$, and $f$ is a function $\overline{a} \to \overline{b}$.

Comment: How does it relate to K?

Comment: It's not clear to me what $\mathcal{N}$ is supposed to be. Perhaps you could clarify that

Comment: I think  $(\bar{a_l}, \bar{b_l},{f})$ is for generators of finite structures of K, but it does not state it clearly since this is only a lecture note. That is why I asked this question. $\mathcal{N}$ is for domain, and I guess $\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})$

Comment: Looking at the notes, I think they have used $\mathcal{N}$ (rather than $\mathbb{N}$) to denote the natural numbers. Very strange.

Comment: That's because $\mathcal{N}$ is not $\Bbb{N}$, but the power set of it.

Comment: @hermes: Why do you say so? I can't seem to find an explicit definition of this $\mathcal N$ anywhere. Whenever $\mathcal N$ is discussed elsewhere in the notes, it seems to refer to an arbitrary structure.

Comment: @tomasz, on first paragraph of the proof, it says "We will construct a structure as required whose domain is a subset of $\mathcal{N}$". The domain is often subset of numbers, but it is just my guess.

Comment: @hermes: So why would you make it a subset of the *power set*?

Comment: @tomasz, that is for combination of all possiblities

Comment: @hermes: That is not what it is at all. A subset of $\mathcal P(\mathbf N)$ is a very different animal from a subset of $\mathbf N$.

Comment: I know a subset of $P(N)$ is a collection of subsets of $N$, no need to be too serious on this.

Comment: @hermes "The domain is often subset of numbers" means that the domain would be an *element* of $P(\mathbb{N})$ (or equivalently *subset* of $\mathbb{N}$), not a *subset* of $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: @ Noah Schweber, I understand this and just typo, and do not take it seriously

Answer (score 1):

I think the author is being a bit imprecise. For the purpose of this proof $\mathcal N$ should be any countably infinite set (well, I suppose it would technically work with any infinite $\mathcal N$, but then it would be slightly more difficult to show that the resulting structure is countable).

The point is that since $\mathcal N$ is infinite and $\mathcal K$ is an amalgamation class of finite structures, the solution to any instance of JEP or AP problem can be found as a structure whose domain is a finite subset of $\mathcal N$ (and in fact even better, it can be realised by extending an existing structure contained in $\mathcal N$ --- this is important to ensure that $\bigcup C_n$ is a structure), so we can choose each $C_n$ to have domain contained in $\mathcal N$. Thus, it makes sense to compare $\bar a_l,\bar b_l$ and $C_n$ (as subsets of $\mathcal N$).

Comment: JEP problem = $A,B\in \mathcal K$. AP problem = $A\leftarrow C\rightarrow B$. A solution to a JEP/AP problem = embeddings of $A,B$ into some $D$ witnessing JEP/AP.

Comment: Ah, yes, these are the standard abbreviations.

Comment: @ tomasz, thanks for your reply. From this post, I still do not understand how finite structures can be represented by tuples of $(\bar{a_l}, \bar{b_l},{f})$, or how is a finite subset of countably infinite set  $\mathcal{N}$ related to finite structures in it? Maybe more background is needed

Comment: @hermes: I don't think any further background is needed. The triples do not represent any finite structures, only finite partial functions. A finite subset of a countably infinite set is, well, a set, and as such you can make it into a finite structure by assigning interpretations to each symbol in the language.

Comment: @ tomasz, I just realize that $\bar{a_l}$ can be considered as the total number of generators and $\bar{b_l}$ the maximum power index of the generators, i.e. a finite structure has the form $x^{n_1}_1\cdots x^{n_l}_l$, where $l<\bar{a_l},\:n_k<\bar{b_l}$. In this way, the proof becomes all clear.

Comment: @hermes: I don't think what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean? Here we need a form for generating all substructure of $K$. $x^{n_1}_1\cdots x^{n_l}_l$ is based upon (free) group, and we assume all substructures are isomorphic to it.

Comment: I mean that $\bar a_l, \bar b_l$ are simply the proper domain and the range of $\bar f_l$. They are meant to represent partial automorphisms, not numbers. There are no groups involved.

Comment: Here it should be modified as $\bar{a}=(n_1,\cdots,n_l)$ and $\bar{b_l}=(max\{n_l\}, \cdots)$. So they could represent partial automorphisms as well.

Comment: More precisely, $\bar{a}=(n_1,\cdots,n_l)$ and $\bar{b_l}=(p_1,\cdots,p_l)$, where $n_k<p_k$.

Comment: @hermes: I don't see how this could be used to represent partial automorphisms. $\bar a_l$ and $\bar b_l$ should just be tuples in $\mathcal N$.

Comment: It is based on (free) group, which means any finitely generated substructure is (partial) isomorphic to it and so can be represented by $f_l(x^{n_1}_1\cdots x^{n_l}_l)$. This may not completely rigorous, of course

Comment: @hermes I've rolled back: "countably infinite" is more precise than "countable," since the latter is often used inclusively (so finite implies countable).

Comment: No problem at all.